# script not working in crontab

Tags: cron

I noticed a number of similar questions ask and I also tried the suggestions posted, but I just can't seem to get this working. Below is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="" read -d "" -r filename;
do
filearray[i++]="$filename"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.txt" -print0)
printf '%s\n' "${filearray[0]}"
```

Simply, I just want to search for all txt type files in a specific directory and put them into an array, which is displayed at the end. When I run from the command line, no problem. It works well. As soon as I execute this via crontab, I get the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `<'
`done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.txt" -print0)'
```

Here's the cron entry itself:

```
* * * * * . /usr/online/scripts/test.sh 2>> /usr/online/scripts/log/test.log
```

Why is the script working on command line, but not crontab? I am declaring the shell, so surely crontab should use the shell? Is there another why I can do this which works?

Jakkie

Comment: How do you invoke it in the crontab?

Comment: Do you set SHELL=/bin/bash in the crontab? Otherwise you're getting /bin/sh behavior

Comment: I have tried that as well, not no luck. I will quickly do it again and check.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying I must add SHELL=/bin/bash at the top of my crontab file, or the script?

Comment: Just a few commands we run. They all work fine by the way. This particular script is the only one using the line causing the error.

Comment: I meant, please include the exact crontab contents (without comments) in your question.

Answer (score 2):

`command < <(other command)` is a [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism). Since you are specifying a shebang line, you should *not* specify a shell in your crontab; that's just confusing. You should do one or the other - I very much prefer a shebang line because you're being explicit about the syntax that follows, rather than pretending to be a "generic" shell script.

Oh, and make sure you're making your script executable and putting *only* `/path/to/your/script.sh` in the crontab command field, **not** `sh /path/to/your/script.sh`, `sh < /path/to/your/script.sh` or even **`. /path/to/your/script.sh`**. The last three ignore the shebang line, and instead runs the script in the context of the cron shell, whatever that is set up to be.

See [redirection instructions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055) for more info on saving script output to a file.

Comment: OK, thanks. So what is wrong then? The command I run from crontab is: * * * * * . /usr/online/scripts/test.sh 2>> /usr/online/scripts/log/test.log

Comment: is that with, or without the "dot", as in . /

Comment: I amended the crontab command as you suggested, but now the log output file is empty. Was the script executed?

Comment: There is no way for me to tell from the available information, but I would very much expect so. Have you checked your cron logs?

Comment: Im sort of new to Linux. Where can I check the crontab logs? Am I correct in saying that if I added the 2>> part to export to a log, that only errors will be sent to the output, not the actual steps? If that is true, then the script should be working now, because the output is zero bytes.

Comment: Not too worry, I found the cron log. There's no error in it though.

Comment: Did you expect there to be an error? It seems your script is now working correctly (although the standard output of the script is not saved anywhere, so I'm not sure what the goal is).

Comment: What I try to achieve is to see the last part of the script in a log of some kind. If you look at the scrip, there is a part where I want to display the contents of the array. I was hoping that the "2>>..." part would do that. How can I display the contents of the array in a log?

Comment: Thank you everyone. It seems to work now. The problem was with the addition of the "dot" and "sh" before the command in crontab. I removed and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @l0b0 the output will be mailed to the local user account

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the script is executable and is doing the right thing when invoked from the command line, write your crontab entry like this (to run every 15th minute):

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/script.sh >/path/to/output 2>/path/to/errors
```